# Cypress randomly fails a test which passes usually and independently

Tags: cypress

Basically, the error is in the image:

This last test passes using `it.only` and sometimes it's 50-50 chance it fails or passes when running all tests together.

I have this `<iframe> placeholder for` on the screen and the error:

`(uncaught exception) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input`

[image]

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: what is the json file you passing?

Comment: none, it's from its chunked js files